# MinGW "The procedure entry point libiconv could not be located ..."

Tags: c, mingw

I've got a standard C library that compiles just fine on Mac OS X using gcc.

I've examined the C compilers available for Windows, and choose MinGW for a couple reasons:

- MS's tools don't support C99
- Cygwin et. al. adds an extra level of complexity with the posix emulation that I don't want
- Can't get lcc-win32 to work

But, when I try to build my library, I'm getting this:

[image]

This stuff all seems very archaic, and there are practically no decent resources online that I can find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

It doesn't matter what I'm trying to build. Even if I just make a single file with a function that adds two numbers. It crashes. Doesn't seem to have anything to do with the source code or the options passed to gcc at all. I think this is a problem with my MinGW setup and not with my project.

Comment: This error is produced when you are building a DLL?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I'm trying to build. Even if I just make a single file with a function that adds two numbers. It crashes. Doesn't seem to have anything to do with the source code or the options passed to gcc at all.

Comment: Clearly your mingw installation is borked. How did you install?

Comment: I installed using the Automated (GUI) Installer. I followed the directions to a 'T'. Located here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: The last time I tried to use the official MinGW installer - which I'll admit was quite a while ago - I was left thoroughly confused.  Unless it's progressed a lot since then (and maybe even if it has), I'd suggest using someone else's distribution.  Nuwen's distribution is a simple unzip operation - http://nuwen.net/mingw.html  And I've never used it, but I've heard good things about the TDM distribution: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/start

Comment: By the way, the `as.exe` I have in my MinGW installation is not dependent on libiconv-2.dll (or any other libiconv.dll).

Comment: I gave up, and worked through my issues with LCC... which, despite a few things I'm wary about, seems to be doing what I need.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure you have C:\MinGW\bin in your path before any other directory that contains `libiconv-2.dll`. Apparently the `as.exe` in some MinGW distributions are dependent on that DLL, and having an older version of it in the path somewhere (for example GnuWin32 tools) will cause `as.exe` to pick up the older version that doesn't have the entry point it's looking for.

See: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3375870&group_id=200665&atid=974439

Note - you should be able to replace the older `libiconv-2.dll` with the newer one in `\MinGW\bin` - the naming of the DLL *should* mean that it's backward compatible with the older one (ie., older software that isn't dependent ont he newer exports should continue to work). However, I haven't tested that so be sure to backup if you do decide to try replacing the conflicting DLL with the one from your MinGW installation.

Comment: Interesting. I DO have GnuWin32 installed. Let me try this and get back to you. I also do have `C:\MinGW\bin` in my `PATH`, but it's *after* GnuWin32 I believe... so if there is a conflict with GnuWin32, I believe the system would be finding the GnuWin32 version *first*. This definitely seems like a plausible explanation of what's going wrong here.

Comment: Bingo. I wish I could give you more up votes. This was exactly the problem (conflict with GnuWin32).

Comment: Cheers chap. While investigating what was going on, I found that I could compile things if I called gcc while my current directory _was_ \mingw\bin. In that instance, as.exe was happy. But any other pwd and it was not. Thanks for this. I was looking at some sort of mismatched dll issue while building, not just that as.exe wasn't starting properly. Cheers.

Comment: I just did a fresh install of MinGW on a machine that has never had a compiler on it before, and the file `libiconv-2.dll` is not anywhere on my system. I am completely incapable of using my installation. Does anyone else have this issue? I never had this issue before using the new installer+manager thing.

Comment: OUTSTANDING ANSWER !!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to making sure C:\MinGW\bin is in your PATH before anything else, you should also restart your machine (or possibly log out/log in), to ensure your PATH is actually updated.