# MinGW “The procedure entry point libintl_setlocale could not be located …”

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake, mingw

I have problem building a project under Windows 7 64bit. I already looked similar questions on SO, but didn't found proper solution. When I run:

```
cmake -v -G "MSYS Makefiles" CMakeLists.txt
```

it gives me following output:

```
> -- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeTestCCo
mpiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programmi
ng/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"
  "cmTryCompileExec1735268707/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  `/c/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMak
eFiles/CMakeTmp'


  "/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
  /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMake
Files/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
  1

  Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

  /c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c
  /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMake
Files/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  make[1]: ***
  [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
```

Also I get next error message 3 times, during compilation attempt, it says "The procedure entry point libintl_setlocale could not be located in the library libintl-8.dll"

CMakeError.log:

> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -Aa
>
> The output was: 1 :0:1: error: missing '(' after
>   predicate
>
> Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+
>   Compiler": gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation
>   terminated. Determining if the C compiler works failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir:
>   C:/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"
>   "cmTryCompileExec2453403923/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2453403923.dir/build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2453403923.dir/build make[1]: Entering
>   directory
>   `/c/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   "/c/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
>   /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
>   1 Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2453403923.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>   /c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe    -o
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2453403923.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj   -c
>   /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /c/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2453403923.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error
>   1 make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2453403923/fast] Error 2
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -Aa
>
> The output was: 1 :0:1: error: missing '(' after
>   predicate
>
> Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+
>   Compiler": gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation
>   terminated. Determining if the C compiler works failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir:
>   C:/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"
>   "cmTryCompileExec78678067/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec78678067.dir/build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec78678067.dir/build make[1]: Entering
>   directory
>   `/c/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   "/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
>   /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
>   1 Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec78678067.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>   /c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe    -o
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec78678067.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj   -c
>   /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
>   make[1]: make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /c/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec78678067.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1 make: *** [cmTryCompileExec78678067/fast] Error 2
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -Aa
>
> The output was: 1 :0:1: error: missing '(' after
>   predicate
>
> Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+
>   Compiler": gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation
>   terminated. Determining if the C compiler works failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir:
>   C:/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"
>   "cmTryCompileExec1735268707/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/build make[1]: Entering
>   directory
>   `/c/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   "/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
>   /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
>   1 Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>   /c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe    -o
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj   -c
>   /C/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
>   make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1735268707.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error
>   1 make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /c/Users/Sony/Documents/Computer_Graphics/assignment_01/programming/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   make: *** [cmTryCompileExec1735268707/fast] Error 2
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 1

Also my Path Environment Variable:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup
>   Setting Tool;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MVActiveX\;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin

I installed and reinstalled mingw and investigated my path variable, but still have no solution. Any ideas, where I am wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I just found the answer to this: I had another libintl-8.dll in my path.

Do this from the command line:

```
where libintl-8.dll
```

Then rename ALL of them except the one in the MinGW tree.

If that fails, then a reinstall of your MinGW tree may be needed. Good luck.

Comment: the "where" command was just what I needed. I had a Lua installation which had that dll as well, and that caused conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Drop libintl-8.dll in System32/SysWOW64 and it should work fine.

Comment: I actually did, I also tried to replace it, but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat ignorant guess, but the problem with libintl-8.dll could arise from path issues.  Somewhere in your path, you could have an older version of the lib with different entrypoints.  Make sure you have the latest version of MinGW and all relevant libraries, and then try moving MinGW\bin to the top of your path variable.

For another example of what appears to be this problem in action, see: [MinGW "The procedure entry point libiconv could not be located ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262362/mingw-the-procedure-entry-point-libiconv-could-not-be-located)

The answer in that linked question helped me resolve a similar problem I was having.

Comment: I saw that link, as thousand other. Sadly, this didn't hlp in my case. I guess, I have wrong configuration to start with.