# MinGW error when compiling C: The procedure entry point libintl_setlocale could not be located in the DLL-file as.exe

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, mingw32

When i try to compile ANY C program with MinGW, I get the error:
(Roughly translated from Swedish)

> "as.exe - Could not find procedure entry point. The procedure entry
>   point libintl_setlocale could not be located in the DLL-file
>   C:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\as.exe"

Followed by a window saying:

> "as.exe has stopped working..."

I just installed MinGW with the following packages:

- mingw-developer-toolkit
- mingw32-base
- mingw32-gcc-g++
- mingw32-gcc-objc
- msys-base

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: [see this question stackoverflow]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262362/mingw-the-procedure-entry-point-libiconv-could-not-be-located

Comment: @mrblonde Thank you! Turned out that lua was conflicting with it.