# Adding my method to OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I want to add new method in OpenCV library. I made my_funct.cpp whose code is as simple as:

`#include "precomp.hpp"
    #include <stdio.h>
    void cv::my_funct(){
      printf("%s\n","Hello world!"); 
    }`

and I added header `CV_EXPORTS_W void my_funct();` to files C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp  and C:\opencv\sources\modules\imgproc\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp. Then I used CMake to build new binaries for whole library, but when I make a new project in which I use my_funct() I get an error:

> The procedure entry point _ZN2cv8my_functEv could not be located in
>   the dynamic link library path_to_this_project\project.exe.

Other opencv functions work just fine. I'm using mingw32 to compile library and the version of OpenCV is 2.4.9. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is this question related to CMake? Please clarify or remove the tag.

Comment: I'm using it to generate build files. So I thought that, maybe, I should do something different than usual in this case and that someone who is more familiar with this program can help me.

Comment: The CMake tag made me look at the question, I don't like to see non-CMake problems, just because people wrongly tag their question.

Comment: Well, I don't know what I am doing wrong during this procedure in which I use CMake, so I put that tag in case there is something I need to do differently in CMake part. I know that it's not likely, but I'm not 100% sure. I agree that this may not be CMake problem, but it is definitely CMake related question. I'm new here so I might have misunderstood on how to use tags.

Comment: @usr1234567 It seems indeed that this problem is related to cmake, as the my_funct.cpp code is seemingly not compiled and not included in the library generated.

Comment: @Curious, why don't you simply append your code to any of the files in opencv\modules\imgproc\src?

Comment: If it was a CMake issue, we cannot find it without some (changed) CMake code.

Comment: I've done that and I'm still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an MinGW run-time error. So going by the assumption that you didn't get any compiler or linker errors while building `project.exe`, your executable most likely doesn't find the matching `.dll` to your `.dll.a` import library (which must have included the `my_funct()` definition).

I would recommend during developments phase - not talking about the [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/install.html) scripting - to add a post-build step using [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html) and [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to copy the right DLL next to your `project.exe`:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET project
    POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy  
                     "<... path to matching DLL ...>" 
                     "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:project>"
)
```

Certainly you could also let CMake find the matching DLL, but before I could go into details there I would need to see your `project.exe` CMake script.

Maybe also good idea - if you are in the process of extending OpenCV code - would be to use [`ExternalProject_Add()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html) to include OpenCV into your project.

**References**

- [MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows - Wiki: Procedure entry point OpenProcessToken? could not be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Procedure%20entry%20point/)
- [MinGW "The procedure entry point libiconv could not be located ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262362/mingw-the-procedure-entry-point-libiconv-could-not-be-located)
- [Getting started with OpenCV 2.4 and MinGW on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7)